# Remove sections of audio in SoX

Tags: wav, sox

What's the easiest way to remove the specified sections of a wav file using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)? Right now I use the `trim` command to break up the file and then concatenate the parts. However, that seems a little tedious and backwards since `trim` takes a section of audio and copies it to a new file, so I have to trim the *opposite* of the the sections that I specify to remove, and then concatenate those. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Might I suggest that you ask this question on http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly but... try:

```
sox  "|sox  in.wav -p trim 0 start" "|sox in.wav -p trim length" out.wav
```

Where `start` is the the offset of the removing area and `length` is the
number of seconds to remove

Example: to remove between 30s and 50s:

```
sox  "|sox  in.wav -p trim 0 30" "|sox in.wav -p trim 20" out.wav
```

**Update** -- a better solution:

```
sox in.wav out.wav   trim 0 =start =end
```

Example: to remove between 30s and 50s:

```
sox in.wav out.wav   trim 0 =30 =50
```